# Does 1000111 word, coded as CRC(Cyclic redundancy) [7,4] code, has errors?

Tags: algorithm, networking, crc

My guess is that there is an error in second bit (from right to left), using 1011 (polynomial of third degree) and XOR division provides remainder = 10. Using table of errors syndrome it is second digit from right.
But i doubt it, because i saw a lot of a bit different algorithms / polynomials from different sources.

Comment: CRC of what? Any value is legal in a CRC. Whether it is correct depends on what it is a CRC *of.*

Comment: CRC of 1000 information bits and 111 as encoded part i hope.